# Nested IF Function Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to use a nested if function in Excel for data in a table but I'm getting an error message saying that I have too many arguments. I tried reading previous answers to similar questions but I'm still confused. Can someone please offer assistance? 
Here is the data:

```
(Cutoff Value:< 22,000;Display Value†: 1 - V Low);
(Cutoff Value:<30,000;Display Value: 2-Low);
(Cutoff Value:<38,000;Display Value: 3- Med);
(Cutoff Value:<46,000;Display Value: 4-High);
(Cutoff Value:>=46,000;Display Value: 5-V High).
```

Here is my Nested IF function:
    `=IF(F2<22,000,"Vlow",IF(F2<30,000,"Low",IF(F2<38,000,"Med",IF(F2<46,000,"high","V high"))))`

Comment: Looks like you got a solution to the question.  Just a suggestion: when you have a long list of threshold conditions, nested IFs can get cumbersome.  Sometimes a better approach is to create a lookup list and use VLOOKUP or INDEX+MATCH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a comma for a thousands separator in your values. Try typing for instance 22000 instead of 22,000 (except if the zeros are trailing decimal zeros the you should use a period.)

I've change the formula to the one below and it works:

```
=IF(F2<22000,"V low",IF(F2<30000,"Low",IF(F2<38000,"Med",IF(F2<46000,"high","V high"))))
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. I tried writing IF(F2<22,000,"V low",IF(F2<30,000,"Low")) to see if I would get the same comment about too many arguments. I did. They also including commas in the thousands place. So I will try your advice right now and let you know. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Charl Pretorius. Who knew that putting commas where they logically belong would cause Excel to say I was putting in too many arguments. I knew my formula was otherwise correct. I'm giving you a virtual hug right now. :-))))))) But I just remembered that I was supposed to have numbers with my words that are in the parentheses. Oh man! :-(. I hope I have no trouble.

Comment: It worked when I added the modification!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I'm so happy. One step closer to completion. Thank you Charl.

Answer (score 0):

check out this video to see how the if function is used.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TxGFmU_SePs&t=24s

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1078716)